# Multiple Users under El-Capitan

Tags: icloud, macos

On a MacBook Air, running OS X El Capitan, can two different Users login to their own User Account while accessing their own individual and different iCloud Accounts?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Simply create a second user:

**Add a user**

1. In Users & Groups preferences, click Add (+) below the list of users.
2. Choose the type of user you want to create from the New Account
   pop-up menu.
3. Type a full name for the new user. ...
4. Enter a password for the user, then enter it again to verify. ...
5. Click Create User.

[Source](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14411?locale=en_US)

Comment: I should add: You will be able to add your different iCloud accounts after the new user is made. :)